# Varias usuarios e key-pair para conexão Github

Tags: linux, github

Estou com dificuldade em configurar mais de uma chave publica no mesmo servidor para usuarios diferentes contas no github.

Estou usando um pc de testes:

```
Linux kali 4.3.0-kali1-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.3.3-5kali4 (2016-01-13) i686 GNU/Linux
```

cada chave encontra-se na pasta de cada usuario `/home/user/.ssh`
A chave do root funciona normalmente para `push` e `pull`.

As demais estão com os seguintes resultados:

```
> ssh -T git@github.com 
> Hi **********! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

> eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" 
> Agent pid 5746

> ssh-add -l -E md5
> The agent has no identities. (ja tentei dar ssh-add para o id_rsa mas não fez diferença)
```

> OpenSSH_7.1p2 Debian-1, OpenSSL 1.0.2e 3 Dec 2015 debug1: Reading
>   configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>   line 19: Applying options for * debug1: Connecting to github.com
>   [192.**.**.**] port 22. debug1: Connection established. debug1:
>   identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_rsa type 1 debug1: key_load_public:
>   No such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /home/****/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
>   file or directory debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>   debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity
>   file /home/****/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No
>   such file or directory debug1: identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_ecdsa
>   type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1:
>   identity file /home/****/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1 debug1:
>   key_load_public: No such file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /home/****/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1 debug1: key_load_public: No such
>   file or directory debug1: identity file
>   /home/****/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1 debug1: Enabling compatibility
>   mode for protocol 2.0 debug1: Local version string
>   SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1p2 Debian-1 debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0,
>   remote software version libssh-0.7.0 debug1: no match: libssh-0.7.0
>   debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git' debug1:
>   SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received debug1: kex:
>   server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com  none debug1:
>   kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com  none
>   debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY debug1: Server host key:
>   ssh-rsa SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 debug1:
>   Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key. debug1: Found
>   key in /home/****/.ssh/known_hosts:1 Warning: Permanently added the
>   RSA host key for IP address '192.**.***.***' to the list of known
>   hosts. debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent debug1: expecting
>   SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received debug1:
>   SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
>   debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: Permission
>   denied debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey debug1:
>   Next authentication method: publickey debug1: Offering RSA public key:
>   /home/****/.ssh/id_rsa debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen
>   279 debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey). Authenticated to
>   github.com ([192.**.***.***]:22). debug1: channel 0: new
>   [client-session] debug1: Entering interactive session. debug1: Sending
>   environment. debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = pt_BR.UTF-8 debug1:
>   Sending env LC_MONETARY = pt_BR.UTF-8 debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC =
>   pt_BR.UTF-8 debug1: Sending env LANG = pt_PT.UTF-8 debug1: Sending env
>   LC_MEASUREMENT = pt_BR.UTF-8 debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = pt_BR.UTF-8
>   debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
>   Hi Laudiceaa! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
>   provide shell access. debug1: channel 0: free: client-session,
>   nchannels 1 Transferred: sent 3400, received 1776 bytes, in 0.3
>   seconds Bytes per second: sent 13429.2, received 7014.8 debug1: Exit
>   status 1

Ja gastei toda munição que tinha na tentativa de resolver o problema, se alguem puder ajudar agradeço muito.